# System quit, logs show no events

Tags: 22.04, crash

Running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 here. Yesterday morning the PC just stopped doing anything. It was unresponsive and needed a hard restart to get going again. journalctl shows nothing unusual up then it just ends, and picks up later in the morning when I rebooted it. I was hoping to find a clue to help me debug the cause of the freeze, but as can be seen, there's nothing to work on.

```
Nov 01 00:00:23 AirchainProcessor sSMTP[480431]: Creating SSL connection to host
Nov 01 00:00:24 AirchainProcessor sSMTP[480431]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Nov 01 00:00:26 AirchainProcessor sSMTP[480431]: Sent mail for kpov_tech@AirchainProcessor (221 2.0.0 closing connection e8-20020a056a00162800b0069029a3196dsm644677pfc.1>
Nov 01 00:00:29 AirchainProcessor CRON[480228]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user kpov_tech
Nov 01 00:05:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480432]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user kpov_tech(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:05:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480432]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user kpov_tech
Nov 01 00:10:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480450]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user kpov_tech(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:10:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480450]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user kpov_tech
Nov 01 00:15:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480465]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user kpov_tech(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:15:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480465]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user kpov_tech
Nov 01 00:17:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480483]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:17:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480483]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 01 00:20:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480486]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user kpov_tech(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:20:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480486]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user kpov_tech
Nov 01 00:25:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480504]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user kpov_tech(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:25:01 AirchainProcessor CRON[480504]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user kpov_tech
**-- Boot 07602d9b639b4840aef4f5b0a8bfe275 --**
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel: Linux version 6.2.0-1016-lowlatency (buildd@lcy02-amd64-037) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GN>
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-1016-lowlatency root=UUID=21d4f32a-398b-4bd6-96fb-3a3e4914bfbb ro threadirqs quiet>
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Nov 01 08:28:55 AirchainProcessor kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
```

Everything prior to the freeze are normal events. Then it just stopped.

I'm wondering if this could have been a hardware fault. And I'm wondering whether anyone here might offer a way to learn more about the glitch. Thank you!

Comment: Linux does that sometimes.  The way I troubleshoot it is to always have an ssh session running fro a different client.  Then tail -f /var/log/syslog.  Then you can see the most recent activity before the hang.  Sometimes the OS isn't even hung, it's just a process that's gone amok.  The symptoms you describe doe snot sound like a hardware problem.

Comment: Don't forget to check the `/var/log/kern.log` file for kernel error reports that typically show in `dmesg`.  There might be items there not reported in your journal (though I don't see any in your output specifically).

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Hm. The event happened at 01:29 on November 1. kern.log shows nothing between Oct 31 and when the PC was restarted later in the morning at 08:26:56. Different ways of looking at journalctl reveal nothing new. The suggestion to keep an open ssh session following syslog looks like a really good idea. Thank you!